# c# web-based crawler

Tags: c#, web-crawler, bots, googlebot

I have several questions concerning crawlers.

1. Can I create a crawler that works purely on web? I mean, a crawler that can be launched or stopped from an admin page of a web-project.
2. What is the most convenient language to write a crawler? I was planning to write it with c#.
3. The most important one: How do the crawlers work? I mean, I know that you create them through the use of `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse`, and I guess that after each page visit, the crawlers will come back and the code will evaluate the result and then create a queue to send the crawler to other websites. So basically if this information is true, considering that I will create the crawler by using a web-project, should I keep the page always up and how big will be the burden of the crawler for the server? Will it slow down the server or it's a relatively small work for it?

I know, there are many questions here and I will really appreciate the answers :)

Comment: why are you guys giving minus points?

Comment: Not to be a jerk, but if you have no idea where to start (especially choosing a language!), you might want to rethink taking on such a large and very complicated project...

Comment: I am doing it for myself. I code for hobby only.

Comment: Writing a viable crawler is a HUGE undertaking.  I thought it was as simple as 'get the page, get the links and repeat'.  How wrong I was.  Yes, Shaokan, do continue, and you CAN create a crawler that lives in a WebPage.  First, look to store where the crawler has been using the filesystem or a sql/no-sql implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)  Absolutely a crawler could work purley on the web.  Your crawler could be either an ASP.NET application, or your administration page could start or stop a task (the web crawler) on the server.

2)  VB.NET or C# works.  They both have extensive libraries for working with the web.

3)  I'd imagine what you're looking for is a recursive function.  First, choose a page to start with on the internet (that contains a lot of links).  For each link within the page, run the crawler's main method again.  Do this over and over.  You'll probably want to limit how "deep" down to crawl.  I'd imagine you'd want to do some work within each page also.

Comment: I won't do any other work on the same page, but there will be users surfing the website, I don't want that the site works slowly :)

Comment: You may consider looking at the domain name of the server.  If you make x amount of calls, add them to a queue and save them for later.

Comment: Recursion is incorrect.  The web contains much more data than your computer can hold.  A queue is what you want to implement.  :)